# Python+Selenium. Click on Java block

Tags: python, powershell, selenium

I'm new to Python.
I have a script that clicks on the ad unit on the site. But now I need to achieve the same in Python.

The object specified in the index.html javascript code

When the page loads the code is transformed into an ad unit, consisting of 3 images with links.

[image]

But it is necessary to click to start to get a reference At least one of the three blocks.

In Google Chrome, the function "View code" gives the following:

[image]

How to find and click on one of the three elements on the page?

Find by xpath or ID or tagname?

Help me please! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Кудрявцева рассказала о безработном сыне..."]').click()
```

P.S. This images could be located inside an `iframe`, so in case my code doesn't work (you get `NoSuchElementException`), try to switch to frame before clicking link:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')) # if there is only one iframe on page
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[1]) # if there are few iframes, just select required by its index
driver.switch_to_frame('iframe_name_or_id') # if iframe has "name" or "id" attributes
```

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://nnmclub.to')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'www.marketgid.com')]").click()

Comment: Thank you! Made is an option. Tell me more as I realize the wait? Once the page is loaded, before clicking, before closing the browser?

Comment: What do you mean `"wait"`? Also there is no `www.marke‌​tgid.com` in `href` attribute on provided screenshot...

Comment: It example,friend. I want wait 10 sec after page loading and then 10 sec after click on link. And then quit browser.

Comment: You can simply `import time` and then add `time.sleep(10)` after each mentioned action to wait for 10 second

Comment: Thank you  friend for your help! Tell me on more!  You are try to use PhantomJS?    browser = webdriver.firefox is worked!   But browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('E:\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs.exe')  NOT WORKING =( Why?

Comment: Just move your `phantomjs.exe` file to `C:\Python` folder and create instance simply as `browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()`

Comment: Thank you!! How do you know whether the Phantom actions done or not?

Comment: How can i see his actions in console?

Comment: You cannot see it. It works as a simple browser, eg `Chrome` or `Firefox`, but just without visual frame. But you still can use `browser.get_screenshot_as_file()` to see what actually happens on page in particular moment of time